# Calculation in SSAS Cube not working for zero data values

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap

I am working with a SSAS 2008 R2 cube and interrogating the data through Excel 2010. In the cube I have a calculation to conditionally format the data. The logic is if a measure contains a specific value for the fact being viewed, then the fact should be colored red, as follows:

```
CALCULATE;     

SCOPE
(
    [Measures].[Data value]
); 

If([Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidential]) Then
    Fore_Color(This) = 255
End If;    

END SCOPE;
```

When I have a [Data value] of 0 (zero) the fore_color doesn't render as red in `Excel`. If I change the data value to anything other than zero, and reprocess the cube it renders as Red.  Is there something I'm missing, or is there a better `MDX` script that would also work for values of zero?

Comment: Are you sure the values where the wrong rendering happens are really 0? Or are they maybe null (i. e. missing records)?

Comment: @FrankPl yes I even tried changing the data from 0 to something else and then reprocessing the cube. When I did that the color rendered as expected (i.e. red). When I changed back to 0 it didn't any more.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an Excel or Analysis Services issue. Could you run an MDX query from Management Studio where you append `CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORE_COLOR` at the very end of the statement (after all FROM and WHERE clauses), and then in the result double-click a cell containing zero to see the FORE_COLOR property value?

Comment: @FrankPl It's definitely a problem that is visible in Analysis Services or Excel. When I click on 0 values in SSMS the cell properties returned show FORE_COLOR = (null).  The values display as black not red too.  I also checked that the value for the confidentiality status is "Confidential" which should result in FORE_COLOR of 255.

Comment: Is `Data value` a calculated or a physical measure? Is it possibly overwritten somewhere else in the calculation script?

Comment: @FrankPl Data value is a physical measure. Only thing that is "unusual" about it is that the name of the underlying field is different from the one presented in the cube. Definitely no other calculations in the script other than the one in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you have the following:

```
If([Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidential] = 1) Then
    Fore_Color(This) = 255
End If;
```

(... so wouldn't expect `0` to render as red?)

Does the following mean data `0` is red?:

```
If([Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidential] = 0) Then
    Fore_Color(This) = 255
End If;
```

Comment: No I don't - I have a table containing a field called confidentiality status and a field called Data value. When Confidentiality Status = "Confidential" then Data Value (which is the scope) renders as red. If Confidentiality status has any other value then Data value shouldn't be red. For some reason if Data value is zero (not null) then it isn't displaying red.

Comment: To further clarify the confidentiality is exposed as a degenerate dimension, but lives in the same table as the data value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SCOPE
(
    [Measures].[Data value], [Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidential]
); 

    Fore_Color(This) = 255

END SCOPE;
```

Alternatively, but less efficient:

```
SCOPE
(
    [Measures].[Data value]
); 

If([Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].CurrentMember IS [Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidential]) Then
    Fore_Color(This) = 255
End If;    

END SCOPE;
```

This sets the foreground color for the measure `Data value` and the `Confidential` member.

What your code does is setting the foreground color if, for the `Confidential` member, the value of the current measure (which is always `Data value` within the SCOPE) is not null or 0. When evaluating a numeric expression as a condition, in MDX everything not 0 or null is evaluated as true. And if you are using a member here, MDX checks its value for the current measure. To check if the current member of a hierarchy is a specific one, you use `IS` as I did in my second version above.

**EDIT**
As the requirement is to check if in the current cell, there is data contained which is related to the confidentiality status "Confidential", no matter if that dimension is contained in the query or not, you can use:

```
SCOPE
(
    [Measures].[Data value]
); 

If(Intersect(EXISTING [Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidentiality Status].Members,
             {[Fact Base].[Confidentiality Status].[Confidential]}).Count = 1 Then
    Fore_Color(This) = 255
End If;    

END SCOPE;
```

This checks if the intersection between all members of the `Confidentiality Status` level of the `Confidentiality Status` attribute hierarchy that exist with the data of the current cell and the one element set consisting of the `Confidential` member has one element, with other words, if the member is contained in the existing members of the level.

Comment: Both solutions work, but they are dependent on the Confidentiality Status being an active dimension - i.e. if it is not used then the data does not change to red.  The initial script in my question did not require the confidentiality status to be selected in a query.

Comment: @Greg What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: @FrankPI I need to be able to show the Data Value as red if its confidentiality status is "confidential" regardless of whether or not the dimension containing the confidentiality status is actually dragged in to the pivot table or not. The initial code that I posted in the question behaves this way except for zero values. I think your solution is close, but I suspect there's another value rather than "CurrentMember" which I could use. Sorry, I'm still new to MDX.